# Let 7Zip install in same directory without subdirectory

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, 7za

When using 7Zip to extract a zip file, it always creates a subdirectory I want to avoid to create.

**The zip file:**

```
C:\Test.zip
```

**The content files in zip file:**

```
`ReadMe.txt`
```

**The Commandline:**

```
x "C:\Test.zip" -o"C:\" -y
```

**The result:**

```
C:\Test\ReadMe.txt
```

**Should be**:

```
C:\ReadMe.txt
```

Can anyone find out the argument to avoid creating the "Test" subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this myself using the latest version of `7za` on Windows 8 64-bit, and 7-Zip doesn't create the "Test" subdirectory.

Are you certain that the zip file doesn't contain the "Test" directory? If it does, you can use the `e` command instead of `x` to prevent it from retaining the archive's directory structure.

Comment: You made my day!! Great thanks for that answer. The option "e" instead of "x" solved the problem.

Comment: I've just found any non responsable documentatino. Do you have any documentation link?

Comment: The only documentation that I know of, besides the program's self-documentation, is [this](http://docs.bugaco.com/7zip/).